I have problem with selection of language it has option of writing
enter image description here
so as you can see there is problem on the left side of the flag when i select it it keeps appearing and it disappears when i changed language i want to get right of it pls help
'use client';

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import i18nConfig from '../../../../i18nConfig';
import Select, { SingleValue } from 'react-select';
import Flag from 'react-world-flags';

const languages = [
    { code: 'en', name: 'English', flag: 'GB' },
    { code: 'ru', name: 'Русский', flag: 'RU' },
    { code: 'kk-KZ', name: 'Қазақша', flag: 'KZ' },
];

type LanguageOption = {
    value: string;
    label: JSX.Element;
};

export default function LanguageChanger() {
    const { i18n } = useTranslation();
    const currentLocale = i18n.language;
    const router = useRouter();
    const currentPathname = usePathname();

    const handleChange = (selectedOption: SingleValue<LanguageOption>) => {
        if (!selectedOption) return;
        const newLocale = selectedOption.value;

        // set cookie for next-i18n-router
        const days = 30;
        const date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        const expires = date.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = `NEXT_LOCALE=${newLocale};expires=${expires};path=/`;

        // redirect to the new locale path
        if (currentLocale === i18nConfig.defaultLocale && !i18nConfig.defaultLocale) {
            router.push('/' + newLocale + currentPathname);
        } else {
            router.push(currentPathname.replace(`/${currentLocale}`, `/${newLocale}`));
        }

        router.refresh();
    };

    const customStyles = {
        control: (provided: any) => ({
            ...provided,
            width: 200,
            height: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            webkitUserSelect: 'none',
            msUserSelect: 'none',
            userSelect: 'none',
        }),
        option: (provided: any, { isFocused }: { isFocused: boolean }) => ({
            ...provided,
            backgroundColor: isFocused ? '#e0e0e0' : '#fff',
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
        }),
    };

    const options = languages.map(lang => ({
        value: lang.code,
        label: (
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Flag code={lang.flag} style={{ width: '20px', height: '15px', marginRight: '8px' }} />
                {lang.name}
            </div>
        ),
    }));

    return (
        <Select
            defaultValue={options.find(option => option.value === currentLocale)}
            onChange={handleChange}
            options={options}
            styles={customStyles}
        />
    );
}


i am expecting it to be normal without it when user wants to change language and it happens with every language i try, also tried to work with cursor different types of it and it didnt work out for me

<Select
        defaultValue={options.find(option => option.value === currentLocale)}
        onChange={handleChange}
        options={options}
        styles={customStyles}
        isSearchable={false}  // Disable text input
    />

that's how decided this problem
